# What is the purpose of declaring an extra local variable in this OpenZeppelin ERC20 implementation?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

From the implementation of ERC20 from Openzeppelin using solidity ^0.8.0, the _transfer function is like this:

```
function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
        require(senderBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[sender] = senderBalance - amount;
        _balances[recipient] += amount;

        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
```

Is there a special purpose of writing

```
uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
require(senderBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
_balances[sender] = senderBalance - amount;
```

instead of simply

```
require(_balances[sender]>= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
_balances[sender] -= amount;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [pull request](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/2506) comment that contains [this commit](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/commit/a44303c373f58c43c4910b78eb6f0a84248a52fd#diff-fa792f7d08644eebc519dac2c29b00a54afc4c6a76b9ef3bba56c8401fe674f6R216) adding the `senderBalance`:

> *The addition of revert messages back into the 0.8 branch (#2491) generated double reading of some storage slot. This PR remove the double sload, which reduces gas costs of running the affected function.*

So it's because of lowering gas usage.

"One read from storage and one from memory" cost significantly less gas than "two reads from storage".